# IE ignoring background, padding and min-height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've got some problems with IE. But I think pictures are worth a thousand words in this case:

Chrome, Firefox & expected result:
[image]

IE 11
[image]

Why doesn't IE present it like I expect? And what can be done to solve this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/edrpuLtk/3/

css

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
html, body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body, header {
    background: #FFFF33;
    background-image: url(../bg1.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 30%;
    background-position: right top;
}
header, main {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
header {
    height: 136px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
main {
    min-height: calc(100vh - (136px + 80px));
    /* 100% minus (height of header plus height of footer) */
    background-color: rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.33);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 136px;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
#content {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

html

```
<header>
    <p>some text</p>
</header>
<main>
    <div id="content">
         <h1>Headline</h1>
        <p>line 1</p>
        ...
    </div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: [IE may not support `<main>` yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic).

Comment: I replaced the `<main>` with a `<div id="main">` an everything works fine. Thanks, please post this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending from comment:

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic), IE still doesn't support `<main>` element, so you may want to use something like `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

All that IE is missing is `display:block` for `main` in its browser stylesheet.

Add that “manually” via your CSS, and all is well:

```
main {
    display:block;
    /* rest of your formatting for main */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edrpuLtk/4/

Comment: Are there any benefits when using main instead of a div?

Comment: Ah yes, your solution is better. It's more HTML5-ish than mine.

Comment: @Passerby: It all depends, on what you set priorities on. If support for IE older than v9 is a priority, then a _HTML5 Shiv_ would be needed to make it recognize new HTML5 elements in the first place, meaning without JS enabled they would not work at all. In that case, going with “old school” elements in favor over semantics might be the better approach.

Comment: @CBroe Given that OP is already using `<header>` and `<footer>`, he may either using shiv already, or don't care about old IE at all. So your solution is still better, or, more "correct".

Comment: Well I’m not going to fight you on that ;-)